# What to watch out for when transitioning to iOS 5

Tags: ios, memory-management, ios5

**Summary:** *Can you add to my checklist of things to watch out for when migrating to iOS 5?*  StackOverflow has been invaluable as I've worked on upgrading to iOS 5.  I've discovered some pretty basic things I'd missed prior to Xcode 4.2, and I'm wondering what other "gotchas" might be lurking.

**Detail:** With iOS 5 shipping this week, I've had to make some changes to a couple of my apps.  Xcode 4.2 does a much better job analyzing memory management code because of the new ARC feature.  The iOS 5 update is a great point at which to review all your memory management code.  The new compiler also finds a number of other issues that earlier compilers missed.  Kudos to the Apple compiler engineers.  Here are the main things that have helped (and many of them will also apply to earlier versions of iOS).

1. Make sure to [call [super dealloc] at the END of your dealloc methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566453/correct-super-dealloc/4566488#4566488), not the beginning.
2. In viewDidUnload, [some people have reported bugs that require [super viewDidUnload] to be called at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365440/iphone-super-viewdidunload-calling-order/5503408#5503408), not the beginning, of your viewDidUnload.
3. Understand retain counts, synthesized setters, and when to call release or autorelease.  The new compiler will point out more problems than the older compilers did.  (I thought I'd been careful, but apparently I wasn't careful enough.)  Apple's [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) is required reading -- no shortcuts.
4. It's a good idea to [turn on zombies when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168327/what-is-nszombie/4168365#4168365) (in Xcode, choose Product | Edit Scheme... and select the Debug scheme; on the Diagnostics tab, check Enable Zombie Objects).  This can help you find attempted uses of zombies (objects you shouldn't be using any more).
5. The Leaks instrument is also helpful.  Run your app in Profile mode and choose the Leaks template.  In the Instruments window, select the Leaks instrument and check the box that says "Gather Leaked Memory Contents" and it will help you see where the leaked memory originates in your code.

There are a few odds and ends I've encountered:

- Apple's [singleton pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) needs "oneway" added to the return type declaration:

```
    - (oneway void) release { }
```

- You may need to [manually add "armv6" as an architecture type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053466/application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture-armv6/7667814#7667814) in your Build Settings (and be sure Build Active Architecture Only is set to NO).

Any other suggestions of potential pitfalls I should look for?  I have a feeling that my apps are more stable now, but I felt pretty good about them before.

Comment: It's not memory management, but it's important anyway: If you download any data and want to store it on the device be careful not to save that into the documents folder. Use Library/Caches or tmp for that. Or store application data into NSApplicationSupportDirectory appended by your bundle id. see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1 for details.

Comment: Not memory management either. But if you are doing Security/Certificate related stuff. Mind that MD5 hashed certificates return kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure on SecTrustEvaluate. Because ios5 considers MD5 hashes not secure.

Comment: Another thing for migrating to IOS5 is the deprecated UDID. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1/ Modal controllers behave differently, if you were changing their size. If you need modal dialog of a different size, consider using iOS 5 child view controllers.

2/ For a table, if you were returning nil section header and positive height, in iOS 4, the header was hidden. In iOS 5, you have to return zero height for nil headers.

3/ UDID is deprecated. You can use CFUUIDCreate to create a unique id and save it into your settings but be aware that a device data can be backed up and then restored to another device, leaving you with two devices with the same id. I solved the situation by saving my id into keychain with attribute kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly.

About your list:
[super viewDidUnload] should be always called as the last statement in your viewDidUnload. The logic is the same as in [super dealloc]. Note, that you should also call [self viewDidUnload] in your dealloc (if you don't already release your memory there) because it is not called implicitly (although sometimes it is).

From my experiments, leak detection in Instruments don't report leaks on properties which are synthesized without assigning a property name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Could you clarify something for me?  I think we're saying the same thing on the question of when to call [super viewDidUnload].  Also, it would improve your answer to illustrate more clearly the suggestion of the circumstances under which you should call [self viewDidUnload].

Comment: In general, if you are using ARC and your IBOutlets are weak, everything gets unloaded when the view is unloaded. But without ARC and with strong (retain) IBOutlets (for example if you are adding and removing them dynamically from the view), you want to release them inside viewDidUnload. However, you want to release them also in your dealloc method. To remove code duplicity, you just call viewDidUnload from dealloc. You should put it there always because it's not called automatically when the view controller is released.